# Date object in the query to show posts from the following month

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I'm building a booking for events, each event is divided into taxonomies, this is the query that regulates my custom post type, to display all the posts that are under the "aperitivi" taxonomy.

```
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  array('eventi-suite'), // your CPT
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array
        (
            'key'     => 'metakey_AMC_data',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => date( 'd-m-y', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) ),
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'aperitivi'
        )
    )

);
```

The problem is that the post date is within the meta_value that corresponds to the meta key:`metakey_AMC_data`, obviously this date inside the db is in the form of a string, reason why in order not to let me exit events that have a date prior to the current one, I got the date through the mysql time table.

My problem is this I can't see the posts between the months.

Example: I see all posts until September 30, 2019, but not those of October 1, because obviously the query does not recognize that the October 1 date is larger than September 30, how can I show all future events?